# Mobilefirst WL.SecurityUtils

Tags: mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

If we encrypt plain text by using WL.SecurityUtils on the client side in Mobilefirst 7.1.0, can we decrypt that string on the server side or on the database side by using any utility given by IBM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope, This is not possible.  `WL.SecurityUtils.encrypt` and `WL.SecurityUtils.decrypt` APIs can be used only in client application.

In your case, You have to implement some custom code to do encryption in client app and decryption in the server.

Comment: Do you have any sample compatible with mobilefirst 7.1, I have some custom routine but that I wrote for my other project and it is in .NET.

Comment: @MichealSmith Sample for encryption and decryption ?? You will get lot in internet.